# Why is this returning undefined when run?

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

```js
function switchBooks(book) {
  book = "the book name";
}

var myBook = "new book";
myBook = switchBooks(myBook);

console.log(myBook)
```

I'm new to JS and want to understand why this is happening?

Comment: There is no `return` in your function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further UnholySheep's comment. You need to return the result of the function in order to access it later in your code.

From [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
> be returned to the function caller.

In your case, the function caller is `switchBooks(myBook);`

```
   function switchBooks(book) {
       var book = "the book name";
       return book; //This is the addition
   }

   var myBook = "new book";
   myBook = switchBooks(myBook);

   console.log(myBook)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return` inside the function.

```
function switchBooks(book) {
 return book = "the book name";
}

var myBook = "new book";
myBook = switchBooks(myBook);

console.log(myBook)
```

Comment: Note that the `book =` does nothing and can be removed.